# File Upload restricted to only 1MB in RHEL 6.4 through PHP script

Tags: php, apache

I have changed the configuration in `php.ini` file to :

```
upload_max_size=100MB;
file_uploads is also ON;
```

But the following code works fine on Windows local server XAMPP. The same script allows to upload any file size to the database. Which is restricted to only 1 MB in Linux.

I have also checked the `my.cnf` file but there is no option for allowing maximum packet size which is available in windows `my.ini` file.

```
// This is the temporary place where it got put on the server
// after it was uploaded
$tempfile = $_FILES["uploadedfile$i"]["tmp_name"] ;

// addslashes so as not to break anything :)
if(!empty($tempfile)){
    //$data = addslashes(fread(fopen($tempfile, "rb"), filesize($tempfile)));
    $data = addslashes(fread(fopen($tempfile, "rb"),filesize($tempfile)));
    $fp = fopen($_FILES["uploadedfile$i"]['tmp_name'], 'rb');
}
// pull out useful bits in case they are needed. 
$filetype = $_FILES["uploadedfile$i"]["type"];
$filesize = $_FILES["uploadedfile$i"]["size"];
$filename = $_FILES["uploadedfile$i"]["name"];
```

**this is the command to upload the file to the database:**

```
$query=$this->db->prepare("insert into $table 
  (filename,data,filexml,filesize,filetype,filetype1,category,filesize1)
  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");  
$query->bindValue(1,$filename,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(2,$fp,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->bindValue(3,$filexml,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(4,$filesize,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(5,$filetype,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(6,$filetype1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(7,$_SESSION['radbut'],PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindValue(8,$filesize1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();   
echo $table;    
echo 'wav eee upload successful';
```

Comment: It's not really a good idea to store large files in a database. Databases aren't designed for it. Better, store the file in the file system and keep the path and filename in the database.

Comment: Is there any way to store in the database though?? As per our project requiremnt we need to store it in the database itself.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` is available in Linux. However your code doesn't check for any errors in your PDO query, so you don't know what the problem is. You should check the return status of your `$query->execute()` call, and look at `$query->errorinfo()` if it's `false`. When you know what the problem really is, fix that.

Comment: It returns true and displays file sucessfully uploaded. but the data doesnot actually uploads in the database

Comment: Please confirm that, your datatype for upload field is BLOB.

Comment: What is the difference between `filesize` and `filesize1`, and the difference between `filetype` and `filetype1` in your database ?

Comment: Sir we are uploading two files .wav file and .textgrid file

Comment: yes it is a BLOB field only!

Comment: filesize is size 4 wav file filesize1 is size of txtgrid file n similarly filetype and filetype1

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information about your configuration to help you completely, but here are some leads you can follow :

- Check the `post_max_size` of your `php.ini` file.
- Check also that the parameters you set in the `php.ini` are succesfully set into your `phpinfo()` (be sure it's not overridden by Apache)
- If you have `suhosin` installed, check its paramters, they can be tricky sometimes
- Check the Apache logs to find more information about what's wrong (and syslog information for `suhosin` errors)
- What is the size of your file and the size of the database field you're inserting into?
- As pointed by Mike, check the `max_allowed_packet` on your `my.cnf` MySQL configuration.
- Be sure you restarted MySQL and Apache after your changed these paramters.

Also as pointed by Mike, MySQL is not designed to store large files.

If you really have to store it into a database, please consider using NoSQL databases, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), with [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) features.

Comment: as mentioned above in my.cnf max_allowed_packet statement is nt present and also if manualy added then (service mysqld restart) fails

Comment: Fails how? What is the error message? Did you put it in the right section? What about the other elements I suggested, and people suggested in comments?

Comment: faills in the sense the service is running and when restarted is stopped n den cannot start again!

Comment: what i have 2 check in Syslog or Mysql Log